# how to avoid random iteration over a map in jsp

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

Hi i am working with spring-mvc and bootstrap , i have to iterate over a map on my jsp ,but the map is iterating randomly , for example if from the controller class i am adding

key = cat,value =1

key = bat,value =2

key = mat,value =6

to  a map as model.addAttribute("map",map)

when i am iterating over this map in my jsp the values which get shown on the page is random as

mat,6
cat,1
bat,2

but is there a way in which i can maintain the same order so that on jsp also i can display

cat,1
bat,2
mat,6

Comment: The `"map"` that you store in your model is most likely a `HashMap` instance, which is not designed to guarantee any iteration order. Just use a `LinkedHashMap` instead (as suggested by @Rembo) and it should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there a way in which i can maintain the same order so that on jsp
>   also i can display

what you want is LinkedHashMap. use it to get insertion order.

see javadoc of [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   **predictable iteration order**. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. **This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order)**. Note that insertion order is not affected if a key
>   is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if
>   m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true
>   immediately prior to the invocation.)